# How to change value of a textbox in a pdf

Tags: pdf, textbox, sed

I have to make several certificates with the same design but different names. So I've tried to make an uncompressed pdf file with a place holder text and tried to change it with a text editor. For some reason it didn't work. I could only see a single letter of the replaced text.

When I try the same thing with an eps file, it works but since eps doesn't keep (AFAIK) page orientation, there is a chance that it something will be different with different names.

Does anyone know why this didn't work or how to change a text box in a pdf file (with sed)?

(I created the master pdf with Illustrator CS4)

Thank you

Comment: Please post what you tried and what the before and after strings are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, editing PDFs in a text editor is a Bad Idea.  PDFs depend on the byte offsets of various objects to not move.

If you KNOW your editor won't change the EOL bytes (or what it thinks are eol bytes), and you DO NOT change the length of the text entry's object as a whole, you're okay.

For example:

`1 0 obj`
`<</Type/Annotation/Subtype/Widget/V(PlaceHolder Value)/T(Field Title)...>>`
`endobj`

If your new value is longer than "placeholder value", you're screwed.

Most PDFs contain quite a bit of compressed binary data.  Some of that data WILL be misinterpreted as EOL characters.  Changing them will:
a: break your compressed stream
b: possibly change the byte offsets of the rest of the PDF.

When I hack on PDF files, I *always* use a hex editor.

Bottom Line:  Don't mess with PDFs as a text stream.  Mess with them as PDF files, using a PDF library.  There's sure to be one capable of altering form field values in your language of choice.

You can also look into FDF and XFDF to see if they'll suit you better.  Both file formats store field/value pairs and a reference to the form to use with those pairs.  FDF uses PDF's syntax, while XFDF is an XML grammar.  You can serve the [X]FDF to your end user and they will see the filled-in form.

WARNING:  Unless the form is Reader Enabled (requires Acrobat (pro?)), they won't be able to save the version of the form they get after opening the [X]FDF, only view/print it.  Of course they can save the [X]FDF, but many users might balk at this Strange New Format.